# Line Plus Bar with Multi Bars?

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js

I'm trying to make an chart using the default line plus bar chart, but I want to use two or more streams in the bars, **is it possible?**

Currently, when I try to do this, I got some trouble with the effects of the chart, and so I can't show properly the hover balloon of the bars, he always display the data of just one of the streams. But the main problem is the dates of x axis, displaying 1970's dates, when I remove the second stream of bars, the dates display well:
[image: Current chart]

Anyone already tried to do this kind of chart successfully?

**EDIT**

Adding Fiddles:

[Fiddle with two columns stream and messy dates](http://jsfiddle.net/mVMMH/)

[Fiddle with just one column stream and ok dates](http://jsfiddle.net/CQ8yE/)

I'm calling this kind of graph:

```
linePlusBarChart()
```

Comment: I don't see any reason why this -wouldn't- work; could you post to a jsfiddle or bl.ocks.org isolating the problem you're having with the dates?

Comment: Just posted the fiddles @AdamPearce, thank you again for answering me!

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the dates is that your data contains timestamps (i.e. in seconds), but Javascript expects milliseconds. This is easily fixed by multiplying the values by 1000:

```
series.values = series.values.map(function (d) {
            return {
                x: d[0]*1000,
                y: d[1]
            }
});
```

The tooltip problem is actually a bug in NVD3 -- it's not meant to be used this way. The problem boils down to the `mouseover` handler assuming that the first item of the data is representative of what you want. You can fix this for your case by selecting the item by data point number modulo 2 (because there're two bars):

```
.on('mouseover', function(d,i) {
        d3.select(this).classed('hover', true);
        dispatch.elementMouseover({
            point: d,
            series: data[i%2],
            pos: [x(getX(d,i)), y(getY(d,i))],
            pointIndex: i,
            seriesIndex: i%2,
            e: d3.event
        });
      })
```

This will only work for exactly two bar series though. Updated jsfiddle with the modified NVD3 code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mVMMH/1/).

Comment: Please, look again. The orange bar is displaying the tooltip of the blue bar. And can you tell me why the dates are displaying correctly in the second example, without making this conversion?

Comment: Thanks @LarsKotthoff! Your jsfiddle is working fine. But there's one left bug, when I click to hidden the orange bar it doesn't hide, just get the blue color. There's a way to fix it?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Nothing happens for me when I click or double click on a bar.

Comment: I mean when I click on the labels (the little balls) on the right top of the graphs, not on the bars.

Comment: I've had another look at it and this particular NVD3 chart is just really not meant to be used with several bar series. Among other things, the scale isn't set up correctly (as you will notice when hiding the blue bars). Fixing it would require *major* changes.

Comment: you indeed can't use multiple bars in a linePlusBarChart (as seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/mVMMH/133/) You CAN use multiple lines thou (http://jsfiddle.net/mVMMH/134/)